# MySQL commit and rollback

Tags: php, mysql

I develop a webpage in that i face this problem. please see below.

In user table i have following fields:

- Userid
- password
- Address
- phone
- Email

In service table i have the following fields:

- Ser_name
- ser_id
- USER_Refid

All these are in same page in php.

When i add values in service table it stores under the same USER_Refid name .

For example the user xxxx is going to add service means the USER_Refid field contain the same name for all services .

My problem is when the user add values in services table and forgot to add the values in user table means i want to delete the values that inserted by that particular user . Please help me to solve this , Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your tables are `InnoDB`, you can a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint to your service table:

```
ALTER TABLE service_table ADD CONSTRAINT fk_service_user_refid FOREIGN KEY (USER_refid) REFERENCES user_table (USER_id)
```

To add the values into services, create a memory table with a session id, populate it with your services, and when the user clicks `Save`, do the following:

- Create an entry for your user in the `user_table`
- Move the entries from the temporary table into the `service_table`.

Comment: At first user can able to add values to service table without store values into user table.[Just to give the value in that Userid field ,the service table take that value for the field USER_Refid]

Comment: Your criteria will apply if the user first store the values in to user table

Comment: Why don't you want to add to the user table first? If your service table records cannot exists without an entry in user table, this makes more sense.

Comment: then what you mean you said can add service without any user then said  you want delete whom add service without any reference?

Comment: That means i used those all in a single page in php . i ask user to enter the userid first and make it as readonly . After that he can add values to the service table. So i can take that readonly field value for USER_refid field .After add many services, the user click the save all button means i insert the value into user table.

Comment: `@Sakhtivel`: for some strange reason you make the `user` entry temporary and `service` entries permanent. Just put your services into a temporary table, and when the user clicks `Save`, move them into the permanent table.